# Can't execute code in Break mode when opening a file in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to open a file in VBA in Excel 2010 and the code looks like this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folder & FileName
```

When I execute the code in Excel 2010, it gives me this error:

```
Can't execute the code in break mode
```

The file I am opening is of format Excel-2003 format. Is it because of this? I have searched in Google and most suggest it is because of Select statement but I am not using one.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Are there any other macros in your workbook that might in the middle of execution?

Comment: Have you tried going into the VBE and tapping Alt+Q then closing the debugger?

Comment: There are not other macros running in the middle of execution

Comment: When I closed the debugger, I was able to run it properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Workbooks.open runs the workbook_open macro in the workbook it opens. If macros are not enabled for the new workbook, it stops.